# Explain instability in Numerics so that I can understand and answer this question that involves roots of a equation

Tags: algorithms, numerical-methods, stability-in-odes

I found this question in my math book:

> **Instability.** For small **|a|** the equation **(x - k)^2 = a** has nearly a double root.  
>  Why do these roots show **instability**?

I read and belive I understood the part in my book about stability and instability but it said nothing about equations, only algorithms.

I guess I don't understand the question and probably understand stability.  
So please explain so that I can learn this properly

Comment: Try an example such as the roots of $(x-7)^2=10^{-20}$ and $(x-7)^2=4 \times10^{-20}$: when $a$ changes by $3 \times 10^{-20}$, the roots change by much more

Comment: I still don't understand why the roots show instability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignore the $k$, that's basically irrelevant. The point is really that if $a,b$ are small positive numbers, then $|\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}|$ is much larger than $|a-b|$. You can see this with a linear approximation: $\sqrt{b} \approx \sqrt{a} + \frac{b-a}{2\sqrt{a}}.$ So $|\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}| \approx \frac{|a-b|}{2 \sqrt{a}}$. Thus the error in the *input* basically gets divided by $2 \sqrt{a}$ in the *output*. This is a small number, so the error in the output is much larger than the error in the input. This is what we mean by numerical instability.

Comment: Is $b$ here the approximation of $a$?

Comment: @Simon They're approximately equal to one another, but I'm not assuming that you're using $b$ as the approximation to $a$ or vice versa. Either way the situation is essentially the same.